# Multiple true answers in javascript array prompt?

Tags: javascript, arrays

So I have a function that basically asks a question and requires the correct answer down to the punctuation; I don't want this.  Is there any way to code it where it will allow "any of these answers"?  Like "yes, of course, absolutely, duh, and/or hell yeah" instead of just "yes"?

My function:

```
function welcome() {
    var questions = [{
        question: 'Are you ready to play?',
        answer: 'yes',
        affirm: 'Yay! You will be presented with a series of questions. If you answer a questions incorrectly, you cannot advance to the next...',
        rebuttal: "No, you're definitely ready to play."
    }];

    for (var i = 0, l = questions.length; i < l; i++) {
        answer = prompt(questions[i].question);
        var correct = false;
        while (correct === false)
        if (answer !== questions[i].answer) {
            alert(questions[i].rebuttal);
            answer = prompt(questions[i].question);
        } else {
            alert(questions[i].affirm);
            correct = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You could either do an array of `['yes','yea','yeehaw']` etc and then check `answers.indexOf(userinput)>-1` - or create a regex along the lines of `/(hell )?ye[psa]h?|absolutely|of course/`. Depends on how specific you do/don't want to be

Comment: Or just use [`confirm()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.confirm) - which is probably much easier!

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the nature of your correct answers, there are several possibilities. I will explain two of them:

**1) Array of possible answers**

You create an array with all the possible correct answers, then check the result of the prompt against it:

```
var correctAnswers = ['yeah', 'ok', 'sure'];

var answer = prompt('Do you...?');
for (var i = 0; i<correctAnswers.length; i++) {
  if (answer === correctAnswers[i])
    result = true;
}

if (result) {
  // acceptable answer code
} else {
  // unacceptable answer code
}
```

PS: you can use `indexOf` to see if a value is in the array, but that won't work with 3) below.

**2) RegExp of answers**

This solution works better than the first if you want to catch variations of the same answer:

```
var correctAnswer = /[yY]es(s?)/; // catches yes, Yes, Yess, yess

var answer = prompt('Do you...?');
if (answer.match(correctAnswer)){
  // acceptable answer code
} else {
  // unacceptable answer code
}
```

**3) Combination of both**

Nothing prevents you from creating an array of regexps and simply match against each of them in turn.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a list of acceptable answers and check what you receive against each one.

Further, you can convert everything to upper or lower case before comparison to eliminate case differences, strip punctuation, convert numbers such as `one` to `1`, and any other transformations you wish.

If you're asking for a function that can comprehend the meaning of any colloquialism or dialectic version in human language you could be a long time coding. Your question suggests six alternatives for 'yes'. A little effort will probably yield six more, and you have the same problem with 'no'. I could go on...

Answer (score 0):

If you need to use `prompt()` you will have to decide on an error margin, as you **will not** cover all possibilities, even with a stupidly long list. Else you can just replace `prompt()` with `confirm()` as this will give you back `true` or `false` which is much easier to deal with. I strongly suggest using `confirm()`, but if `prompt()` is required, some options are below:

**Array of specific options**

Not great because of very limited combinations, more possibilities make for a much larger array, plus you may end up needing an indexOf polyfill (unless you add a custom loop)

```
var questions = [{
    question: 'Are you ready to play?',
    answers: ['yep','yes','yea','yeah','hell yeah','hell yea','absolutely','duh','of course'],
    affirm: 'Yay! You will be presented with a series of questions. If you answer a questions incorrectly, you cannot advance to the next...',
    rebuttal: "No, you're definitely ready to play."
}];

if(questions[i].answers.indexOf(answer) > -1) //.indexOf may need polyfill depending on supported browsers
```

**Beastly regex**

More flexible and shortens code for more options, but could have small performance issues compared to straight string comparisons

```
var questions = [{
    question: 'Are you ready to play?',
    answer: /((hell[sz]? )?ye[psa]h?|absolutely|duh|of course)!*/i, //matches "hell yea","hells yea","hellz yea","hell yeah","yep","yes","hellz yeah!","hell yesh" .... etc plus the full words at the end
    affirm: 'Yay! You will be presented with a series of questions. If you answer a questions incorrectly, you cannot advance to the next...',
    rebuttal: "No, you're definitely ready to play."
}];

if(questions[i].answer.test(answer))
```

**Array of regexes**

Combines issues of first 2, but makes the regex easier to manage

```
var questions = [{
    question: 'Are you ready to play?',
    answers: [/ye[psa]!*/,/(hell )?yeah?!*/,/absolutely!*/,/duh!*/,/of course!*/,/yeehaw!*/]
    affirm: 'Yay! You will be presented with a series of questions. If you answer a questions incorrectly, you cannot advance to the next...',
    rebuttal: "No, you're definitely ready to play."
}];

var saidYes = false;
for(var j=0,c=questions[i].answers.length;j<c;j++)
{
    if(questions[i].answers[j].test(answer))
    {
        saidYes = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

**Use confirm() - personal recommendation**

Simplifies whole process by removing possibility of varying responses

```
var answer = confirm(questions[i].question);
var correct = false;
while (correct === false)
{
    if(answer)
    {
        alert(questions[i].affirm);
        correct = true;
    }
    else
    {
        alert(questions[i].rebuttal);
        answer = confirm(questions[i].question);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Change

```
answer: 'yes'
```

To

```
answer:[' y e s ' ,'of course', 'absolutely', 'duh', 'hell yeah']
```

Or create a variable of the answers and use that instead.

Comment: I tried this as it required the least modification (I know it's probably not the best, but there's actually only a few answers I would be looking for for the purpose of this)...

However, the above did not work.